# Mixins: passing argument to the 3rd parameter only

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm new in Less and have a problem about this...

I have this code

//Mixin

```
.border(@width: 1px, @type: solid, @color: #fff){
      border: @arguments;
}
```

//Implementation

```
.class{
     .border(#ff0000);
}
```

Is there any possibility to change only @color param in border mixin.When I set value to @arguments, it don't give me possibility to change one of params.
Maybe there is a smarter way to code this..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Named Parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters):

```
.class {
      .border(@color: #ff0000);
}
```